I get 'int' data instead of an array when I load a file using numpy
I got a file, which doesn't have an extension, but I think it's a npy file. When I use np.load, I get an int. How do I open it?
I tried to change numpy version, but it doesn't help.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.load('/opt/data/private/msl/data_thumos/Rgb_TestPJ2_All/video_test_0000006', allow_pickle=True)
>>> a
119547037146038801333356

I'm sure this is a npy file, but I don't know how to get the data.
I tried fromfile, I get array with the shape of (10211,), which loses the original shape:
with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
    data = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.float32)

If I use
with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
    print(f.read(200))

the output is b'\x80\x02\x8a\nl\xfc\x9cF\xf9 j\xa8P\x19.\x80\x02M\xe9\x03.\x80\x02}q\x00(X\x10\x00\x00\x00protocol_versionq\x01M\xe9\x03X\r\x00\x00\x00little_endianq\x02\x88X\n\x00\x00\x00type_sizesq\x03}q\x04(X\x05\x00\x00\x00shortq\x05K\x02X\x03\x00\x00\x00intq\x06K\x04X\x04\x00\x00\x00longq\x07K\x04uu.\x80\x02ctorch._utils\n_rebuild_tensor_v2\nq\x00((X\x07\x00\x00\x00storageq\x01ctorch\nDou'.

Are you sure that you have the correct file path? You say you have a file with the extension .npy but the only file path mentioned in your example does NOT have a file extension. What does the file you want to read look like when opened with a text editor?

I tried opening it with a text editor, but it was garbled; @Joooeey

NPY files should begin with a magic string \x93NUMPY. I don't see that in the data dump you show. The \x80\x02 would correspond with a Pickle file using protocol version 2.


the output is b'\x80\x02\x8a\nl …

What you have does not look like a .npy file. It should start with something like b"\x93NUMPY\x01\x00v\x00{'descr': '<i8', 'fortran_order': False, 'shape': (), } ….
It's more likely that you have a pickle file. Try:
import pickle

with open('/opt/data/private/msl/data_thumos/Rgb_TestPJ2_All/video_test_0000006', 'rb') as f:
    a = pickle.load(f)


thanks for your reply, but the result is still 'int'.
'python /opt/data/private/msl/Rgb_TrainPJ2_All/check.py'
'119547037146038801333356'

I have solved the problem. The lesson this incident taught me is that when the file does not have an extension, we should try multiple opening methods, such as np.load, pickle, torch.load, etc.
Solution
import torch

data = torch.load(file_path).float()

